# Adding .jar to Eclipse 2018-09 project

Tags: eclipse, jar, db4o

I'd like to know how to add JAR file to Eclipse 2018-09 project. I've already copied it to lib project's folder. I've tried right clicking on jar file and build path but no actions are displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a Java Project as created with that wizard? Are you right clicking in the Package Explorer view?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a Java Project you want to right click on the project go to properties, click on Java Build Path in the preference tree then on that tab click libraries and on there click add jar and then select the jar you want to add to your classpath.

If you are building a eclipse plugin, open the MANIFEST.MF file go to the runtime tab in the editor and on the bottom right there is a classpath selection, click add and point to the jar you want to add to your classpath.